# Home server filesystem

Tags: server, filesystem, lvm, btrfs

I'm planing to build a home server to act mainly as a uTorrent download and file server for me and the people I live with. I have come up with the following filesystem configuration and I would like some input about its suitability and also what filesystems would be appropriate.  I plan to implement all of it via LVM so I can add HDDs when the prices come down again.

systemvg (16Gb SSD):

1. rootlv (/)
2. swaplv

datavg (500Gb HDD):

1. homelv (/home)
2. volatilelv (temp storage where files are automatically erased after 24 hrs)
3. downloadslv

The users home folders as well as the volatile and downloads partitions will be shared via Samba.

The only formats I have used are ext3/4 because I've only installed Ubuntu on desktop, what will be suitable in this case? I like the snapshot functionality of BTRFS so I can get a system up and running and revert back to in the case something goes wrong, although I'd need a separate /boot partition in this case. Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 2):

On file systems, I would be looking at simplicity and just use ext3/4 and use some file backup utility to snapshot file contents not drive state.

It's not a file system recommendation, but why not use [this](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/torrentserver).

Comment: While I do like the idea of keeping it simple, I'm also using this as a learning experience. I want to get a feel for what is possible and what people use on a larger scale. I appreciate your response nevertheless...

Comment: No problem.  I just fixed the link btw

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't put swap on an SSD. If RAM shouldn't be enough look into [zram](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/10/increased-performance-in-linux-with.html) swap and make it higher priority than your SSD swap. That way it swaps only when really needed.

btrfs is a really nice choice. To reduce writes on the SSD you can also enable compression (add `compress` or `compress=lzo` to your `/etc/fstab`) should you write to the SSD often.

Also imho LVM isn't needed on the SSD.

Comment: I see you point about LVM and swap on the SSD... The point of using LVM is to make it easy to add HDDs at a later stage, something that will not effect the partitions on the SDD... and I didn't know about zram, thanks for the heads up...